# Probability of x elements chosen from the same group

Tags: r, probability

can anyone please help me with the following problem and tell me how to solve the problem by using R?

I have two groups (groupM and groupF) with 9 elements each (M1:M9 and F1:F9).

I want to randomly sample 4 elements from these groups:

```
#Make the sample reproducible
set.seed(11)

#two groups with 
groupM <- c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10")
groupF <- c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10")

groupAll <- c(groupM, groupF)

sample(groupAll, 4, replace = FALSE)
```

What is the likelihood that all 4 elements are chosen from the same group? How to I calculate this probability and how do I solve this problem by using R?

Comment: There are 10 elements in each in your example, not 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bas explained this is a hypergeometric distribution: and hence could be computed as:

```
dhyper(4,9,9,4) * 2
[1] 0.08235294
```

or simply:

```
 2* choose(9, 4) / choose(18, 4)
 [1] 0.08235294
```

For the simulation Part:

```
mean(replicate(40000,mean(sample(x, 4))%in%1:2))
[1] 0.0829
```

Comment: Thank you both. But why to I have to multiply the dhyper function by two? Let's say there are 40 balls in the urn. 22 are black, 18 are white. I draw 5 of them. All are black. Why should I multiply by two?

Comment: @feder80. In that case you won't miltiply by 2. In the question asked, you wanted to know whether they are from the same group. Either MALE OR FEMALE. if you would have been asked whether all were male, then no need to multiply by 2. If you would have been asked whether all are female then no need to multiply by 2. And i am multiplying by 2 since the probability of all being male is the same as all being female.

Comment: I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways in which we can choose 4 from all 18 elements is
`choose(18, 4)` (=3060) ways.
The number of ways in which we can choose 4 from `groupM` is `choose(9, 4)` and the number of ways in which we can choose 4 from `groupF` is also `choose(9, 4)`.
Choosing all 4 from 1 group is therefore `choose(9, 4) + choose(9, 4)` (we either choose all from `groupM` or all from `groupF`.

Therefore, the solution is `(choose(9, 4) + choose(9, 4)) / choose(18, 4)` which is `0.0824`.

You can simulate this by, for example,

```
#Make the sample reproducible
set.seed(11)

#two groups with 
groupM <- c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9")
groupF <- c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9")

groupAll <- c(groupM, groupF)

mean(replicate(100000,
          {
            perc_male <- mean(startsWith(sample(groupAll, 4, replace = FALSE), "M"))
            same_group <- (perc_male == 1) | (perc_male == 0)
            same_group
          }))
```

which samples using your code, and checks whether all elements of the sample start with `"M"` or `"F"`, and replicates this experiment 100000 times.